# Tomcat HttpHeaderSecurityFilter filter entry ignored in conf/web.xml

Tags: tomcat, filter, clickjacking

I am trying to enable the HttpHeaderSecurityFilter filter in Tomcat in order to combat click-jacking attacks. I want this applied to all applications, so have un-commented the default <filter> and <filter-mapping> entries for this filter in Tomcat's own conf/web.xml file.

This seems to be completely ignored by Tomcat though from what I can tell. I added a META-INF/context.xml file to one of my web apps as follows, in order to see the effective web.xml file Tomcat uses for the app after merging the conf/web.xml file with the app's own file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Context logEffectiveWebXml="true"></Context>
```

The resulting output in catalina.log looks valid (content of both files merged) with the exception that the filter entries from conf/web.xml are missing. I have tried introducing my own additional filter entries there and found those also do not appear in the effective web.xml.

If I copy the HttpHeaderSecurityFilter filter and filter-mapping entries to the web app's own web.xml file, it works fine (but this is obviously not what I want!)

Is there some trick to making Tomcat honour the filter entries in conf/web.xml?

I ultimately need this to work in both Tomcat 7 and 8.  (I am aware the built-in filter was only added in Tomcat 7.0.63.)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this filter started working for me without any particular change (very unsatisfying resolution, but...). There is some possibility it was working from the outset, though I'm reasonably certain I had observed pages being successfully loaded in iframes with the filter initially in place. Just not sure now.

What was a possibly useful finding for others though is that the effective web.xml log output never did contain the filter details in it even when I was able to verify that the filter was working. This would appear to be a Tomcat bug of some sort. (Note, I only tested the effective web.xml logging on Tomcat 8.)